# Sum of count of records in three related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery

I have three related tables:

- Course
- Student
- Teacher

Each `course` is given by a `teacher` to many `students`.

I can find the number of students attending a course:

```
SELECT c.id, count(*) FROM course as c, student as s
WHERE c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I can find all the courses given by a teacher:

```
SELECT t.id, c.id FROM course as c, teacher as t
WHERE t.id = c.teacher_id;
```

I want to find how many students were taught by each teacher. Is the following query correct one?

```
SELECT t.id, sum(x.count_s) 
FROM 
   (SELECT count(*) AS count_s FROM course as c2, student as s
      WHERE c2.id = s.course_id AND c2.id = c.id
      GROUP BY c2.id) as x, 
   course as c, teacher as t
WHERE t.id = c.teacher_id;
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test it directly because this is actually a simplification of the real problem at hand. I need to find out which solution works for the simplified problem.

Comment: Can a teacher teach more than one course?  If so, they might end up teaching the same student twice.  If that happens, do you want to count the student once, or once for each course?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: there would need to be some common identifier for a student on the student rows, given that the student table includes a course_id column (FK to course(id)). In this example, the entity represented by "student" is not an individual, but rather, an enrollment in a course.

Comment: In that case you should re-think your database design so that each student only needs one record no matter how many courses he takes.  Essentially, you want a many to many relationship because a course can have many students and a student can take many courses.  If this does not sound familiar, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, no.  You cannot reference `c.id` inside the inline view aliased as `x`. That should throw an error.

But if you remove that, then your query has the potential to return an inflated count, due to a semi-Cartesian product, between the inline view aliased as `x` and `c`.

So that predicate needs to be relocated, and you'd need to return c2.id from `x` (i.e. add it to the SELECT list, you already have it referenced in the GROUP BY).

This is equivalent to your query, just rewritten to replace the comma join operators and relocate join predicates to ON clause. This statement is equivalent to yours, and is invalid):

```
SELECT t.id
     , SUM(x.count_s) 
  FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS count_s 
           FROM course c2
           JOIN student s
             ON c2.id = s.course_id
            AND c2.id = c.id        -- INVALID here
          GROUP
             BY c2.id
       ) x
 CROSS                              -- no join predicate 
  JOIN course c
  JOIN teacher t
    ON t.id = c.teacher_id
```

To fix that, add c2.id to the SELECT list in `x`, and relocate that predicate. Something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , SUM(x.count_s) 
  FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS count_s
              , c2.id                 -- added
           FROM course c2
           JOIN student s
             ON c2.id = s.course_id
       --   AND c2.id = c.id          -- relocated (removed from here)
          GROUP
             BY c2.id
       ) x
  JOIN course c
    ON x.id = c.id                    -- relocated (added here)
  JOIN teacher t
    ON t.id = c.teacher_id
```

Assuming that `id` is UNIQUE and NOT NULL in `course`, that query will return a reasonable count (although counts of zero will be "missing").

To return the "zero" counts, you'd need to use an OUTER join. And as I always prefer to use LEFT JOIN, the tables/inline views in the outermost query would need to be re-ordered:

```
SELECT t.id
     , IFNULL(SUM(x.count_s),0)
  FROM teacher t
  LEFT
  JOIN course c
    ON c.teacher_id = t.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT count(*) AS count_s
              , c2.id                 -- added
           FROM course c2
           JOIN student s
             ON c2.id = s.course_id
       --   AND c2.id = c.id          -- relocated (removed from here)
          GROUP
             BY c2.id
       ) x
    ON x.id = c.id                    -- relocated (added here)
```

Assuming that `id` is a PRIMARY KEY (or equivalent UNIQUE and NOT NULL) on each table, then that will return a "correct" count.

It's not necessary to include the `course` table in the inline view aliased as `x`. It would be sufficient to GROUP BY s.course_id.

```
SELECT t.id
     , IFNULL(SUM(x.count_s),0)
  FROM teacher t
  LEFT
  JOIN course c
    ON c.teacher_id = t.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT count(*) AS count_s
              , s.course_id 
           FROM student s
          GROUP 
             BY s.course_id
       ) x
    ON x.course_id = c.id                 -- relocated (added here)
```

That query will return a valid "count".

---

A simpler statement would easier to understand. Here's how I would get the count:

```
SELECT t.id        AS teacher_id
     , COUNT(s.id) AS how_many_students_taught
  FROM teacher t
  LEFT
  JOIN course c
    ON c.id = t.course_id
  LEFT
  JOIN student s
    ON s.course_id = c.id
 GROUP
    BY t.id
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use `LEFT JOIN` on course against student because it is impossible for a teacher to teach on students that have no courses.

```
SELECT  a.id as Teacher_ID,
        b.id as CourseID,
        COUNT(c.studentID) totalStudents
FROM    teacher a
        INNER JOIN course b
            ON b.teacher_ID = a.id
        LEFT JOIN student c
            ON b.id = c.course_ID
GROUP   BY a.id, b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the distinct count of students a teacher has taught, then this should work:

```
SELECT t.Id, COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)
FROM Teacher t 
   LEFT JOIN Course c ON t.id = c.teacher_id
   LEFT JOIN Student s ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY t.Id
```

If however, you'd prefer to know how many students were taught in each course by each teacher, then try this:

```
SELECT t.Id, c.Id, COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)
FROM Teacher t 
   LEFT JOIN Course c ON t.id = c.teacher_id
   LEFT JOIN Student s ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY t.Id, c.Id
```

Good luck.

Comment: I see no need for a left join.

Comment: @DanBracuk - In case a teacher has taught no students, this will return 0 by using a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: In which case you should add the mysql version of ifnull to your select clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- Not sure how using an ifnull will return records if no students exist for that course (or if no course exist for that teacher).  Using an INNER JOIN will not return the teacher in those instances (regardless of ifnull).  By using a LEFT JOIN, we guarantee the teacher will return in the results.  Best of luck Dan!

Comment: The ifnull is used for display, not to get records.  Like this:  ifnull(COUNT(DISTINCT s.id), 0) students.